# Uncaught TypeError: Not enough arguments

Tags: javascript

i made this code to overwite all the window function and put a console.log after the function run but it giving me error what is the prob??

Uncaught TypeError: Not enough arguments

```
for (func in window) {
    if (typeof window[func] === 'function' && typeof window[func] != 'undefined') {
        var s = window[func];
        window[func] = function (a) {
            s(a);
            console.log(func);
        }
    }
}

alert("hehe");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another poster mentioned, the problem is that your variable `s` is getting overwritten each time through the loop. Instead, try

```
function overwrite(f){
    return function(a){
        var ret=f(a);
        console.log(f);
        return ret;
    };
}

for (func in window) {
    if (typeof window[func] === 'function' && typeof window[func] != 'undefined') {
        window[func]=overwrite(window[func]);
    }
}

alert("hehe");
```